# Unexpected error in double linked list in C

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

I am trying to insert elements in my double linked list based on the number of nodes `n`. Like if `n` is `4` then number of elements entered are: `34 45 32 1` but getting `segmentation fault`. Can anybody tell me where I am going wrong?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>

struct node{
            struct node *prev;
            struct node *next;
            int info;
            }*start;

create_list(int num)
{
 printf("Hi I entered!\n");
 struct node *q,*tmp;
 tmp= malloc(sizeof(struct node));
 tmp->info=num;
 tmp->next=NULL;

 if(start==NULL)
 {
  printf("Hi I am null!\n");
  tmp->prev=NULL;
  start->prev=tmp;
  start=tmp;
 }

 else
 {
  printf("Hi I am no more null!\n");
  q=start;
  while(q->next!=NULL)
  q=q->next;
  q->next=tmp;
  tmp->prev=q;
  }
}




int main(){

int choice, n, elem,i;
start = NULL;

 printf("Enter your choice of number: \n");
 scanf("%d", &choice);

 while(1)
      {

switch(choice)
{
  case 1:
     printf("Enter the number of nodes: \n");
     scanf("%d", &n);

     for(i=0; i<n; i++)
     {
       printf("Enter the elemnts: \n");
       scanf("%d", &elem);
       create_list(elem);
     }
     break;

 default:
         printf("You have tyoed wrong!\n");
     }

   }
 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(start==NULL)
{
  ...
  start->prev=tmp;
```

If `start` is NULL, then the assignment above is incorrect.

I would suggest initializing `prev` to NULL when you allocate the new node like this:

```
tmp= malloc(sizeof(struct node));
tmp->info=num;
tmp->next=NULL;
tmp->prev=NULL;        // add this

if(start==NULL)
{
    printf("Hi I am null!\n");
    start=tmp;
}
....
```

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to dereference a NULL pointer here:

```
if(start==NULL)
{
    printf("Hi I am null!\n");
    tmp->prev=NULL;
    start->prev=tmp;    //start is NULL
```

Since pointer to struct `start` does not point to any memory, you can't use it to asing data.

Comment: what shall be the assignment then?

Comment: @user227666 You have to point start to a valid chunk of memory. `start= malloc()` would be start.

Answer (score 1):

You have an infinite while loop. Set some variable after you have finished inserting into the list. check this variable after coming out of the switch case and break again from the while loop.