# Double linked list insertion trouble

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

Can anybody give me link or good tutorial or link of any book where insertion and deletion of double linked list are given. I need to create 2 functions: one for inserting an element after a position and deleting an element after a position. I am finding many on-line programs but quite not understanding the algorithm or logic behind it. Can anybody explain me what is happening in insertion or deletion after a certain node? What I understood till now is node is declared globally as:

```
 struct node{
             struct node *prev;
             struct node *next;
             int info;
            }*start;
```

What does this `*start` mean here?

Comment: Can you all tell me the reason for down voting. I am really new to data structures and trying to understand not wanting a ready made code!!

Comment: *(I haven't downvoted, but...)* you start by asking for a tutorial recommendation (generally not appropriate for this site), then shift to asking about two functions (you didn't show any piece of either function), and finally ask about structure syntax in C.   **Ask a single, clear, concise question.**

Comment: @abelenky I just tried to be specific that what I need to understand and how much I understood till now, as don't want to copy paste, I want to understand what's happening.

Comment: @user227666 see the answer in your previous question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18763139/unexpected-error-in-double-linked-list-in-c ,please remove this question.if you require any additional info ask in with the help of  comments.

Comment: @Gangadhar still didn't get any good tutorial for double linked list

Comment: @user227666:  You can try to justify your question to me, but the fact is, *I didn't downvote*.  I tried to do you a favor by explaining the likely reasons for the -4 downvote.  You can accept that information, or cry about it, but you still asked a bad question and got downvoted.

Comment: @user227666  try to understand this example http://www.lemoda.net/c/doubly-linked-list/ provided in one of the answers , take paper and take a dry run...by creating double linked list. with n number of nodes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume you iterate until the Nth element (found via index or a search criteria).

**INSERTION**

You want to insert node fooitem between *Nth and Nplus1th = Nth->next

1) Back up a reference of Nth->next

```
node *Nplus1th = Nth->next; //save it for now
```

2) Overwrite Nth->next

```
Nth->next = &fooitem; //The next of Nth references fooitem
```

3) Set the next of fooitem to the backed up reference of this->next

```
fooitem.next = Nplus1th;
```

4) Set the previous of the backed up next to fooitem reference

```
Nplus1th->prev = &fooitem;
```

5) Set the fooitem prev to Nth

```
fooitem.prev = Nth;
```

**DELETION**

You want to delete node fooitem between *Nth and Nplus1th = Nth->next

```
node *fooitem = Nth->next;
Nth->next= fooitem->next; //"forward bridge" to next->next
fooitem->next->prev = Nth; //"backward bridge" to prev->prev

//Delete references for safety
fooitem->prev=NULL;
fooitem->next=NULL;

return fooitem;
```

**IMPORTANT**: The above code assumes that the (N+1)th node is not NULL. A check must be included to verify this assumption when trying to access this node's next or prev references.